# "Talking" with a windows service C#

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, named-pipes

I need a good and easy way to "Talk" to a windows service in C#
I have been able to create a windows service and start, stop, pause and continue  it using a windows forms application.
My question is
Which is better and/or easier to accomplish this? WCF or Named Pipes? Or is it easier to do it using a file and make the service check it after some interval continuously?
I am very unfamiliar with both concepts(wcf and named pipes). So basically what i am asking is:
Which is worth my time? WCF or Named Pipes?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: i dont understand? why cant you use run->services.msc to start,stop etc why do you need to create a seperate windows form to control your windows service?

Comment: @Dexters Lots of services have control/management applications that let you configure/interface/restart etc the service. Not an unreasonable thing to want to do. Also, if this is software made for non-technical users, it's much easier to tell them to use the application that comes with the service, and not to go into the services manager.

Comment: Not sure what your question exactly is, but maybe you're looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just provide a simple interface in **c#** with the following codes for doing what you wanted `start,stop,restart` etc

http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

additionally, you may want to look into

`SC` commands which are specifically a way to interact with windows services..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682107(v=vs.85).aspx

or even `WMIC`  for remote access

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dexters. However this is not what i am looking for. Let me elaborate. I need the service to send text messages using a GSM modem which i have done, but then i need to send a 'reply' back to my application which can 'inform' the user that 'x' number of messages have been sent. i need to do this since windows services do not have a UI. 
Now i can handle telling the service to start sending messages using the OnCustomCommand(int) method but to converse with the application from the service, which control should i use?

Comment: can i have a serial port which both components listen to and send the messages through their OnDataRecieved functions? if it is possible then is it a good practice?

Comment: @user3381338 .. i dont quite understand. But one way is to make your service poll a database every 10 or 15 minutes.. And your reply can be somewhat dumped into the database. So that way you dont communicate to your application directly but through a database.

Comment: isn't there another way?have you had any experience with named pipes? because the examples that i found on named pipes are too complex :(

Comment: @user3381338 if you post it as another question on what you have tried, you might get help.